# Написать регулярное выражение для нахождения даты

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение для нахождения даты формата гггг/мм/дд в js. Имеется готовое регулярное выражение для поиска даты формата гггг-мм-дд, но как только я пытаюсь заменить тире на слэши, перестаёт работать

```
let re = RegExp('(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что слеш должен быть экранирован.

```js
let re = RegExp('(\\d+)\/(\\d+)\/(\\d+)');

// TEST
[
  '2022/09/22',
  '99999999/9999/0000',
  '2022/09/DD',
].forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str+' - '+re.test(str));  
});
```

А вообще это немного не правильная регулярка, лучше уточнить кол-во символов.

```js
let re = RegExp('(\\d{2,4})\/(\\d{1,2})\/(\\d{1,2})');

// TEST
[
  '2022/09/22',
  '22/9/22',
  '99999/09/DD',
].forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str+' - '+re.test(str));  
});
```

---

А если прям ещё точнее хотите, то можно вообще так - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26972181/7692602

Comment: `99999/09/DD` почему вы написали это, не написали вариант с нормальными днями? это выражение вполне пропустит год с троку с 5ю цифрами в годе, отфильтровав 4 нужных, т.к. ограничители начала конца строки не установлены. Нужно удостовериться, что перед 4хзначным годом стоит что-то отличное от цифры.

Answer (score 0):

```
const re =  /\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/g
```

или

```
const re =  /\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/g
```

В первом варианте 2022/1/1 - будет валидной датой, а во втором нужно чтобы дата была такой: 2022/01/01